# How do i remove title textview in view flipper after button is clicked?

Tags: android, text, title, viewflipper

I created an android app that has viewflipper...
The screen flips to another view after button is clicked. 
The first view is meant to show text shown and the second view and the rest the text shouldnt show.
but how do i remove the textview below when the next views are shown?

```
<TextView
android:id="@+id/custom_font"
android:textStyle="bold" 
android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal" 
android:text="@string/titlesfourq2" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_y="10dip" android:textSize="20dip" android:layout_width="340dp" android:textColor="#000000" android:layout_x="35dip"/>
```

This is my xml.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <AbsoluteLayout android:id="@+id/LinearLayout01"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="vertical">

<AbsoluteLayout android:id="@+id/radioGroup1"
android:orientation="vertical" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">

                    <Button android:background="@drawable/board" android:id="@+id/bg"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    </Button>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/custom_font"
    android:textStyle="bold" 
    android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal" 
    android:text="@string/titlesfourq2" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_y="10dip" android:textSize="20dip" android:layout_width="340dp" android:textColor="#000000" android:layout_x="35dip"/>

    <Button android:background="@drawable/buttonred" android:id="@+id/buttonredfailone"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dip" android:textStyle="bold" android:textSize="35dip" android:typeface="sans" android:layout_height="100dip" android:layout_width="100dip" android:layout_x="190dip" android:layout_y="70dip">
    </Button>

        <Button android:background="@drawable/buttongreen" android:id="@+id/buttongreenpassone"
        android:layout_marginTop="150dip" android:textStyle="bold" android:textSize="35dip" android:typeface="sans" android:layout_width="100dip" android:layout_height="100dip" android:layout_x="290dip" android:layout_y="160dip">
    </Button>

        <Button android:background="@drawable/buttonblue" android:id="@+id/buttonbluefailone"
        android:layout_marginTop="150dip" android:textStyle="bold" android:textSize="35dip" android:typeface="sans" android:layout_x="50dip" android:layout_height="100dip" android:layout_width="100dip" android:layout_y="130dip">
    </Button>

</AbsoluteLayout>

    <ViewFlipper android:id="@+id/ViewFlipper01"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" 
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
     >
        <!--adding views to ViewFlipper-->

            <Button android:background="@drawable/blank" android:id="@+id/blank"
        android:layout_width="1dip" android:layout_height="1dip">
    </Button>

            <Button android:background="@drawable/failbg" android:id="@+id/fail"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    </Button>

    <AbsoluteLayout android:id="@+id/two"
android:orientation="vertical" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <Button android:background="@drawable/buttongreen" android:id="@+id/buttongreenfailtwo"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dip" android:textStyle="bold" android:textSize="35dip" android:typeface="sans" android:layout_height="100dip" android:layout_width="100dip" android:layout_x="190dip" android:layout_y="70dip">
    </Button>

        <Button android:background="@drawable/buttonblue" android:id="@+id/buttonbluefailtwo"
        android:layout_marginTop="150dip" android:textStyle="bold" android:textSize="35dip" android:typeface="sans" android:layout_width="100dip" android:layout_height="100dip" android:layout_x="290dip" android:layout_y="160dip">
    </Button>

        <Button android:background="@drawable/buttonred" android:id="@+id/buttonredpasstwo"
        android:layout_marginTop="150dip" android:textStyle="bold" android:textSize="35dip" android:typeface="sans" android:layout_x="50dip" android:layout_height="100dip" android:layout_width="100dip" android:layout_y="130dip">
    </Button>

</AbsoluteLayout>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make the `TextView` invisible by calling `textView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE)`. `textView.setVisibility(View.GONE)` will also make it "non-existent" means it won't occupy any space on the screen while being invisible. Hope this helps.